# Delete orphaned one way lookup data

Tags: apex, delete, execute-anonymous

I have a set of records `supplier__c` which have a lookup to an `address__c` record.

So I'd like to gather all those up:

```
//Make a list of ID's of addresses on Suppliers : supadrs
List<Id> supadrs = [ SELECT Address__c FROM Supplier__c ];
```

Then lets gather all the `address__c` ids:

```
//Make a list of all address IDs : adrids
List<Id> adrids = [ SELECT Id FROM Address__c ];
```

And let's find all the address ids which are not on a supplier record:

```
//Make a list of ID's in List 2 which are not in List 1 and assign to List 3
list< Id > deletelist =[ SELECT Id FROM adrids where Id not in:supadrs ];
```

And then delete the list:

```
delete deletelist;
```

What would be the correct syntax for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in a single query. In fact, you can do this in a single line of code:

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM Address__c WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Address__c FROM Supplier__c)];
```

The second query automatically maps the Address__c values to the Id, allowing for an efficient query that doesn't involve any extra lines of code or clever manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [anti-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin) here:

```
SELECT Id FROM Address__c WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Address__c FROM Supplier__c)
```

That will give you all Address records that are not looked up to from any Supplier.